# Nothing happens when I synchronize with MercurialEclipse

Tags: mercurialeclipse

I'm using MercurialEclipse 2.0.0 in STS 2.9.2.  When I attempt to synchronize a project with its central repository, it works for some projects, but for other projects nothing happens - the Synchronize view does not appear, nor does an error message.  I can do "Synchronize With..." and choose the repository every time, but that's cumbersome. What's different between the projects that would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is happening with multiple people.
Resolution TBD.

For now, an explicit "Synchronize With..." that brings up the explicit dialog is the safest bet.

[Team/Synchronize question](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/339/team-synchronize-question)
[Pinned synchronizations lost in MercurialEclipse 2.0](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/342/pinned-synchronizations-lost-in)

Answer (score 2):

Open up the *Mercurial Repositories* view.  Right click on the central repository that your local repo was cloned from-->Properties.  Fill in the login/password fields if they're blank (strange, though, because in our central repos credentials aren't required until you actually push).  Re-try the synchronize.